# facebook share dialog with select pages tab in android

Tags: android, facebook

I am using facebook sdk 3.5.2. I want to implement facebook share dialog with option to share the post on a specific page.

Code for share dialog.

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(getActivity())
                        .setLink(linkUrl)
                        .setName(teamName+" - "+newsTitle)
                        .setDescription(linksDexcription)
                        .build();
                        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

Share dialog in the current situtation is like that
[image: Image 1]

I want to customize the dialog in this style.Take this picture from facebook android app when user wants to share an existing post from his wall. You can see a tab to select page or group at the bottom of the image 2

[image: Image 2 taken form android facebook app]

Comment: This is currently not possible with the native share dialog.

Answer (score 2):

According to [official](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/) Facebook api, you can see in their screen shots that it is not possible. It's 100% depends on them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible with the native share dialog.